# Kubernetes: Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Connection error: Unauthorized client refused: auth mismatch)

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I am trying to connect my Kubernetes pod container to VSCode on local and I am following these steps:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/attach-container#_attach-to-a-container-in-a-kubernetes-cluster

I am able to connect it to the pod but when I try to access the file system inside the pod I am getting this error:

[image]

Just more details, the filesystem is mounted inside the pod from an external PVC we have on our data storage.

Here's the log generated inside the pod while the connection is being set up. [image]

I think that there's some permission issue someplace in the setup but unable to narrow it down.

Comment: Is everything works fine inside Kubernetes - pod, PVC, PV? Are there any mistakes? Can you connect to a filesystem in a container directly from Kubernetes?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to the filesystem in a container directly.

Comment: I have been using the same inside the VIM environment without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the latest version of the Remote-Containers extensions.
Here's the fix discussed. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6578